Math but stats for studies?
Any ideas why Americans say Math but Stats, for these two subjects of study - mathematics and statistics? I know medical use of 'stat' is from latin with different sense.

Speaking for all Americans, undoing our system, and even thinking about making things consistent, hurts the brain. You can take that to the banks. And that's the truth.

We also say "sports" but Brits say "sport". We say "go to the hospital" while Brits say "go to hospital". There's no why to any of this, it's just the styles that have emerged.

A Brit would say ' go to the hospital ' under the appropriate circumstances

Not an answer, so only a comment, but OED has math. appearing first in 1847 as an actual abbreviation complete with full stop. It became math some time between 1891 and 1961 (the examples between those dates don't make the distinction).

I seem to remember reading that the abbreviations 'math' and 'stat' are most common in the US, 'maths' and 'stats' [both senses] in the UK, and 'math' and 'stats' in Canada.

In its entry for mathematics, Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003)offers a hint at why U.S. and (I believe) Canadian English prefer math to maths:

mathematics n pl but usu sing in constr (1573) 1 : the science of numbers and their operations, interrelations, combinations, generalizations, and abstractions and of space configurations and their structure, measurement, transformations, and generalizations 2 : a branch of, operation in, or use of mathematics

The key observation here is that mathematics is a plural noun but is usually construed as singular (at least in North America). The short form math has been around for a long time, albeit originally with a period at then of the word to indicate its truncated status. Still, according to an Ngram graph tracking "mathematics" (blue line) versus "math" (red line) versus "maths" (green line) in U.S. publications over the period 1800–2019, the frequency of occurrence of math really started to take off around 195o. It eventually matched and surpassed the frequency of occurrence of mathemetics in 2013.
In contrast, here are the entries for mathematics and maths in The Penguin English Dictionary, revised edition (1969):

mathematics n (pl) the science of magnitude and number.
maths n (pl) (coll) mathematics.

And in The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Current English, sixth edition (1976):

mathematics n. pl. (also treated as sing.) (Pure) ~, abstract science of space, number, and quantity; (applied) ~, this applied to branches of physics, astronomy, etc.; (as pl.) use of mathematics in calculation etc.
maths n. (colloq.) Mathematics {abbr.}

The corresponding Ngram graph for "mathematics" (blue line) versus "math" (red line) versus "maths" (green line) in British publications over the period 1800–2019 shows a rise in the frequency of occurrence of maths starting in the early 1950s, much as math began its ascent in North American English at about the same time. However, the progress of maths has been rather jagged, whereas math describe as strikingly smooth curve from as early as 1920 until 2017. The form math also becomes relatively frequent in British publications from the early 1960s onward, and especially since about 2006—but I attribute this to the proliferation of North American content in material published in the UK. There is also an unrelated term math in Indian English that confounds the search results, especially the early ones, to some extent.
With regard to usage Sidney Greenbaum & Janet Whitcutt, Longman Guide to English Usage (1988) offers this discussion:

mathematics 1 This is used with a singular verb when speaking of the science of numbers: Mathematics is my best subject. When it means the mathematical operations involved in a problem or field of study it is often treated as plural: The mathematics of this subject are complex. 2 The common British abbreviation maths takes either a singular or a plural verb, in the same way as mathematics. The American form math is straightforwardly singular.

So in a region where mathematics was usually construed as singular, regardless of how it was used, the short form math gained preeminence; and in a region where mathematics was usually or very frequently construed as plural the form maths prevailed. So far, the situation seems unsurprising.
The Ngram graph for "statistics" (blue line) versus "stats" (red line) versus "stat" in U.S. publications over the period 1800–2019 is useful only insofar as it shows that the frequency of usage of both stat and stats is dwarfed by the frequency of usage of statistic. This is true even though virtually all of the matches for stat and stats reported by the Google Books search results do not involve short forms of statistics until the middle 1960s.
In my experience, most people in the U.S. tend to refer to the study or field of statistics as statistics,, not as stat or stats. The short forms are typically reserved instead for referring to individual statistical results—"the stats on underage drinking" or "an eye-opening stat," for example.
This impression is borne out by the entries for stat, statistic, and statistics in the Eleventh Collegiate:

stat n (ca. 1961) STATISTIC—usu. used in pl.
...
statistic n {sing. of statistics} (1880) 1 : a single term or datum in a collection of statistics 2 a : a quantity (as the mean of a sample) that is computed from a sample; specif. : ESTIMATE 3b [defined as "a numerical value obtained from a statistical sample and assigned to a population parameter"] b : a random variable that takes on the possible values of a statistic
...
statistics n pl but sing or pl in constr 1 : a branch of mathematics dealing with the collection, analysis, interpretation, and presentation of masses of numerical data 2 : a collection of quantitative data

So in U.S. English, according to Merriam-Webster, stat is specifically and exclusively short for statistic, not statistics, and it follows that stats is the plural of stat in the sense of "statistic," not a short form of statistics in the "branch of mathematics" sense. Use of stats in the sense of "the mathematical field or study of statistics" is so little established in U.S. English that the Eleventh Collegiate doesn't acknowledge it at all.
